# three divs side by side with middle div expanding

Tags: css

I want three divisions side bu side with the middle explanding and the other two positioned at the ends. So here is what I tried. The padding rule disturbs the positioning but its necessary. I want approach which works in all major browsers(So ruling out flexbox)

```css
.Button {
  width: 80%; /*Useless Rule*/
}
.Button > .left {
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
}
.Button > .right {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}
.Button> .middle {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="Button">
    <div class="left">&lt;</div>
    <div class="right">&gt;</div>
    <div class="middle">Middle</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is the size of left and right button known?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use the `display: table` on the parent, and the `display: table-cell` on the children. Then give the first and third child a width of 1px. It will then be only as width as its content.

```css
.button {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.button>div {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
}
.button>div:nth-child(1),
.button>div:nth-child(3) {
  width: 1px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div>&lt;</div>
  <div>Middle</div>
  <div>&gt;</div>
</div>
```